# Vue Navigation Drawer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am utilizing a **v-navigation-drawer** with the expand-on-hover prop. When it is in its mini variant, I would like to hide the textbox and button at the bottom. The navigation drawer has computed properties, one of which is **isMiniVariant**. Set to true when collapsed and false when expanded. How can I use this property to bind a style to the div that contains the items I would like to hide?

The codepen/code can be seen below:

https://codepen.io/emicion/pen/zYqerGo?editors=1000

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-navigation-drawer permanent left app expand-on-hover dark>
    <v-list-item>
      <v-list-item-icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-message</v-icon>
      </v-list-item-icon>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title class="title">Application</v-list-item-title>
        <v-list-item-subtitle>subtext</v-list-item-subtitle>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>

    <v-divider></v-divider>

    <template v-slot:append>
      <!-- I want to hide all of this below -->
      <div class="pa-2">
        <v-textarea no-resize outlined placeholder="Enter comment here..." rows="2"></v-textarea>
        <v-btn dark outlined small>
          <span>Add Comment</span>
        </v-btn>
      </div>
    </template>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
  </v-app>   
 </div>
```

[Computed properties listed on VNavigationDrawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj6jJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is:

add to style

```
.v-navigation-drawer--mini-variant .hideme {
  display:none;
}
```

add class to the div you want to hide

```
<div class="pa-2 hideme">
```

Actually, the better way is to add `v-list-group--sub-group` to the class of the div

```
<div class="pa-2 v-list-group--sub-group">
```

Both are kind of hacky, but I've tried using v-list-group's directly, but it's not easy

Comment: @ChristopherAndrewCalderon - found a better way, just adding a class to the div